# How to create a custom poll on facebook via open graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I wanto to create on my facebook page (facebook.com/genericco) a custom poll, in it I wanna create funny polls people can vote on (mainly yes or no answers) and I'd like to post on the voter's wall the action (john doe voted yes on Genericco's poll: Do you think chicken-fish should stop smoking for health issues?).

So I could not do that just using graph API and reading my own questions...so I decided to use the open graph! I created an action called vote with the custom property answer as a boolean...

I've also created the object poll with image,question, title, description and the custom property question...

I've also populated with custom data in the aggregations part.

Then i used Putty program to run the code and be able to submit my custom action for approval...

My question now is...How do I use it? How do I put this together to achieve the objectives I've proposed on the top of this question?

can anyone shed a light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So...I managed to build the customized poll app with Open Graph in facebook. its going well...but its not 100% yet. let me tell you guys why:

1 - So I managed to understand how to creat an action, I called it "Vote", it is connected with the Object type "Poll" I created; The action "Vote" has 2 custom properties: "Answer" wich is a String and "Name" wich is also a String;

2 - Then I created the object "Poll" and I filled it with sample data and stuff and also I created the custom property "Question";

3 - Then I created the aggregation "Enquete Ociosidade" (roughly translating would mean sloth poll) and the data is displays is the action "vote" and in the Caption I used something like this {poll.question}{name} thinks {answer};

Then to make it work I had to send a sample of the action to facebook somehow, I had no idea how to do this so I used Putty and simply pasted the code facebook provides for that; It worked;

Then comes the hard part, how would my front-end app send those info to facebook so I could register the action? Well I'm glad you asked!

I tryed till it worked...YOUR APP MUST HAVE PUBLISHING_ACTIONS PERMISSION THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT!

so...this is the code I got working:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    //alert(response.name);
    FB.api('/me/genericco:votar_poll&enquete=http://www.limonadaweb.com.br/genericco/poll_data.php&resposta='+resposta+'&nome='+response.name+'&access_token='+_token+'' ,'post',  function(resp) {
    if (!resp || resp.error) {
        alert('Error occured '+resp.error.message);
        //mostrar caixa de diálogo que algum erro ocorreu;
    } else {
        alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + resp.id);
        //fazer algo legal para demonstrar que deu certo o voto;
    }
    })
});
```

what I did was...first I make a FB.api call to get the users name, in the callback I make a FB.api call to register the action VERY IMPORTANT TO PASS THE ACCESS_TOKEN TOO...and must be POST.... and that is all there is to it! very cool right? And all that code is inside a function my app calls whenever the user votes and sends a boolean value that I use as the answer to know if the user voted 'yes' or 'no'.

That is all very good and is working fine! Just fine....

My problem now is that now when the action is published in my timeline and newsfeed and stuff it sends the user to this link below...it has absolutely nothing visual in it...it is the poll's data...a bunch of metatags...

i'd like to know if it is possible to send the user to another link when he/she clicks the link of my feed...

http://www.limonadaweb.com.br/genericco/poll_data.php?fb_action_ids=10150744684398313&fb_action_types=genericco%3Avotar_poll&fb_source=other_multiline